# Get last index of duplicate element from arraylist

Tags: java, android, arraylist

I have string arraylist

```
[rose,flower,banana,parrot,rose,bird,flower,rose,banana,bird]
```

From this array I want last index of each duplicate element means it should give me the index for

> rose=6 flower=5 banana=7 bird=8 parrot=4

So that I can get the last element from duplicates.
I don't want to use hash method to remove duplicate because i want to keep index of element.
I have tried to looping through this array but it is not working for me.
My code is as follows.

```
for(int i=0;i<ProductName.size();i++){
                String uniquename = null;

                for(int j=0;j<ProductName.size();j++){
                    if(ProductName.get(i).equals(ProductName.get(j))){
                        uniquename=ProductName.get(i);

                    }                                       
                }
                if(uniquename != null){
                    UniqueproductName.add(i,uniquename);

                }
            }
```

Also I want result array as arraylist

Summery :

I want all elements from array but there are duplicate then i should get the last index of that duplicate element.But i don't want to use Hash method as well as I want result as a `Arraylist<String>`

Comment: Your example contains duplicates for all entries: will this _always_ be the case?

Comment: What if a String occurs only once?

Comment: @fge : This is not the case.Please check my edited question.

Comment: Your example contradicts what you say: you say you want the last index of _duplicated_ elements, and your desired output contains `parrot` which is _not_ a duplicate, so what is what?

Comment: @fge I have edited the Post and added the summery of what i want as a result

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a `Map<String, Integer>` to collect the indices, then build your result from this map:

```
public final class Foo
{
    private static final List<String> productList = Arrays.asList(
        "rose", "flower", "banana", "parrot", "rose", "bird", "flower", "rose",
        "banana", "bird"
    );

    private static List<String> indicesFor(final List<String> list)
    {
        final Map<String, Integer> indices = new HashMap<String, Integer>();

        final int size = list.size();

        for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
            indices.put(list.get(i), i);

        final List<String> ret = new ArrayList<String>(indices.size());
        for (final Map.Entry<String, Integer> entry: indices.entrySet())
            ret.add(entry.toString());
        return ret;
    }

    public static void main(final String... args)
    {
        System.out.println(indicesFor(productList));
        System.exit(0);
    }
}
```

Output of the above code:

```
[bird=9, banana=8, rose=7, parrot=3, flower=6]
```

Comment: But I want my output array as a arraylist<string>

Comment: Done, see edited answer. Strange thing that you want the result as an array: the map's .toString() would return pretty much the same...

Comment: Please help me to understand because i didn't see any .toString in above code.
also can i use `List<string>` as a `ArrayList<String>`

Comment: Well, just try the code and `System.out.println()` the produced map, you will see that the result is very close from what you ask already, without the need to use an `ArrayList`

Comment: Look at the edited code, there is a sample demo code. As you can see, this is pretty much what you want.

Answer (score 2):

You haven't mentioned about the case when a `String` occurs only once. But in general, you can use [lastIndexOf](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#lastIndexOf%28java.lang.Object%29) method of the `ArrayList`.

Comment: Thanks for your answer Swapnil.But in this array String can occurs only once

Comment: Can you please explain it using code.If I have the String which can occur only once

Comment: `lastIndexOf` will find out the last occurrence of the String. If it occurs only once, then be it.

Comment: Note that if performance is an issue this solution is very inefficient relative to some of the alternatives. If not - it is the simplest and probably easiest to understand one, and there is no reason not to use it.

Comment: Yes. When I answered, it looked like a different question and was edited later.

Answer (score 0):

You can **go from last to first** while maintaining the data so far seen in a set:

```
Set<String> set = new HashSet<String>();
for (int i = list.size()-1; i >=0; i--) { 
  if (!set.contains(list.get(i))) {
        System.out.println(list.get(i) + " " + i);
        set.add(list.get(i));
  }
}
```

Note that the tiem complexity of this solution is `O(n)` on average, while iteratively using `lastIndexOf()` is `O(n^2)`.

Comment: What's the point of going from last to first when you have to traverse through the entire array?

Comment: @Vic: The point is `indexOf()` is itself `O(n)`, so iteratively using it is `O(n^2)`, while going from last to first while maintaining a set of "seen data" reduces the time complexity to `O(n)`.

Comment: no, I'm saying you can maintain a set of "seen data" while going from first to last. No need for the other way around even though it's the same complexity.

Comment: @Vic: You can maintain it in a `Map<String,Integer>` - and yes, if doing so, going from start to end will be very similar, however - if you produce the data to some other components (and stream it for example) - going from last to first might have better *latency* - since you start producing answers right from the beginning, while when going from first to last - you produce all data at once - when you are done.

Answer (score 0):

**-** Use the `ArrayList` method `lastIndexOf()`.

**Eg:**

```
public class T4 {

    public static void main(String[] args){

        ArrayList<String> ar = new ArrayList<String>();
        HashMap<String,Integer> ax = new HashMap<String,Integer>();
        int count = 0;

        ar.add("rose");
        ar.add("flower");
        ar.add("flower");
        ar.add("Parrot");
        ar.add("rose");
        ar.add("bird");
        ar.add("flower");
        ar.add("rose");
        ar.add("banana");
        ar.add("bird");

        for(String x : ar){


            ax.put(x,ar.lastIndexOf(x));
        }

        for(Map.Entry<String, Integer> map : ax.entrySet()){

            System.out.println(map.getKey()+"- "+map.getValue());
        }

    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this class:

http://code.google.com/p/synthfuljava/source/browse/trunk/common/org/synthful/util/HashVector.java.

Here is the description:

http://code.google.com/p/synthfuljava/wiki/HashVector.

It is a class that allows elements to be accessed both by key or by position.

If thread-safety is not your concern, you should rewrite the class by replacing HashTable with HashMap and Vector with ArrayList.

Just as I had done in the following to allow it to be compilable by GWT:

http://code.google.com/p/synthfuljava/source/browse/trunk/gwt/util/org/synthful/gwt/util/HashList.java

---

In fact, an expansion of the capabilities of this class is a framework to build a hash tree that allows the key to be an xpath:

http://code.google.com/p/synthfuljava/wiki/HashTree

which consequently led to hashvector tree:

http://code.google.com/p/synthfuljava/source/browse/trunk/common/org/synthful/util/HashVectorTreeNode.java

which allows access by xpath key or hierarchical xpath-like index sequence.

I had not seen much practical use to these classes that I wrote, but I thought it was a good academic exercise to write some classes that had these features. However, HashVector and HashList are well-exercised/exorcised classes that I use frequently.